# [GAE Java]: WARNING: Not using any credentials

Tags: java, scala, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the Java API [example](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/getstarted/start_java/) they create a `Datastore` by using `DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv`

But this creates the warning

```
WARNING: Not using any credentials
```

and leads ultimately to:

```
DatastoreException(null): beginTransaction 401
```

I set my environment variables to the following:

```
export DATASTORE_DATASET={Project-ID}
export DATASTORE_HOST="https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1/datasets/{Project-ID}"
export DATASTORE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT="{email address}"
export DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE="{path to local p12 keyfile}"
```

But still when I try to see what the credentials are:

```
println("Datastore helper: " +DatastoreHelper.getOptionsfromEnv
  .dataset(datasetId).build().getCredential)
```

I get `null`, what could be missing?

Also is there either a way to set the Credentials inside the project (instead of using the `getOptionsfromEnv`)?

Comment: What environment are you running in (Compute Engine, locally, AWS)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that even though I used

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to refresh my environemnt variables and the `echo` command showed me that they were indeed updated, apperently I needed to restart my terminal (using `Mac OSX`) for them to be also updated for `sbt` and `Scala`.

I am not sure why this is the case and if this is `Scala` specific but now I managed to authenticate and communicate with the server.

I managed to figure it out by using the local installation of the [Datastore Server](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver) and continuing to have the same problems.